# Javascript accessing class variable from an inherited class method defined in parent

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Well, I am new to prototype programming / design. 
I would be happy for a help.

The question is why my "`this.__proto__instances`" inside "find" method returns "undefined"?

If my approach is wrong, forgive me, I will be happy to know the correct approach for calling a class method to find an element in a class variable array, without having the method to be defined for every child.

The problem in details is elaborated as comments in the code below.

Thank you.

```
function Attribute(name,type){
    //some members definition, including uid, name, and type
};

Attribute.prototype.find=function(uid){
    var found_attr=false;
    this.__proto__.instances.forEach(function(attr){ 
        if (attr.uid == uid) found_attr=attr;           
    }); 
    return found_attr;
};
```

`this.__proto__.instances.forEach(function(attr){`  above is the erroneous line. Log says "cannot call method forEach of undefined"

```
function ReferenceAttribute(arg_hash){
    Attribute.call(this,arg_hash.name,arg_hash.type); 
    //some members definition
    this.pushInstance(this); 
};
```

`this.pushInstance(this);` pushes this instance to ReferenceAttribute.prototype.instances that works fine

```
ReferenceAttribute.prototype=new Attribute();
```

ReferenceAttribute inherits Attribute with prototype chaining method

```
ReferenceAttribute.prototype.instances=new Array();
```

Line above declares array containing all instances of reference attributes.
For every new object of ReferenceAttribute, it will be pushed into this array, done in a method pushInstance() .
The pushing is always successful, I checked them via console logging. The array does contain the ReferenceAtribute instances

```
function ActiveAttribute(arg_hash){
    Attribute.call(this,arg_hash.name,arg_hash.type);
    //some members definition
    this.pushInstance(this); 
};

ActiveAttribute.prototype=new Attribute(); 
ActiveAttribute.prototype.instances=new Array();
```

use it in the program

```
var ref_attr=ReferenceAttribute.prototype.find("a uid");
```

gives the error  saying that it cannot call method forEach of undefined. 
It can call method find, so it gets inherited well. But "this._*proto*_instances" inside find method definition is wrong I guess.

**EDIT :**

```
Attribute.prototype.pushInstance=function(my_attribute){    
    this.__proto__.instances.push(my_attribute);    
};
```

this function works. Although instances array is possessed by either ActiveAttribute or ReferenceAttribute, and not Attribute itself, but this function does work in pushing it to the array.

Comment: Thank you. I will make some edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're doing this:

```
var ref_attr=ReferenceAttribute.prototype.find("a uid");
```

The `ReferenceAttribute.prototype` object is an instance created from the  `Attribute` constructor, and `Attribute.prototype` has no `.instances` property, nor is there a `.instances` property defined directly on the object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. I did some edit in the code. There is a pushInstance() method defined as a method of Attribute. It is called in the constructor of both children. And this method does work in pushing the instances to the Array. I do notice that the difference with "find()" is that pushInstance is called from a child's instance (object), while find() is called not from a child's object, but rather in a class context. What is your suggested approach for this?

Comment: Invoke it from an instance of `ReferenceAttribute` instead of from the constructor's prototype, so that it will reach that instance's Array. `(new ReferenceAttribute).find("a uid")`

Answer (score 2):

user2736012 has your answer, so just a comment:

The `__proto__` property is not standardised or supported by all browsers in use, so don't use it. Further, if you want to access properties of an an Object's `[[Prototype]]`, use standard property resolution:

```
this.instances
```

If you're going to reference inherited methods directly, what's the point of inheritance?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The solution by user2736012 works that I need to create a dummy instance of child attribute. Regarding your question above, my purpose is so that I do not need to define "find" method for every child. Say I have many children inheriting attribute, how could I write that method only once? My question is already resolved, but I will really be thankful if you have few minutes to help with advice.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess it is my fault to define instances array for every child, but wanted to have only 1 method to access them. It is an architectural flaw. Probably, you have a suggestion/page link that shows how I should have implemented them?

Comment: You just need to set *this* to the right object in the call, so if you call it as a method of an instance, you'll the the right *instances* array (per user2736012's comment).

Comment: Thanks..I guess I still need to learn how "this" works in more detail in javascript.

Comment: Most explanations on the web are not very good, so read a few and know that they are either wrong in some aspect or not clear. The best resource is [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.1), but it's a bit turgid. [This article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is pretty good.

Comment: Sure, the ECMA big book you given really is the complete source. Thanks.